# Using ORA_ROWSCN for archiving a table from source to remote database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have a huge table that gets a lot of transactions but doesn't have timestamp column to know when it was updated. One of our DBAs suggested that we can use a ORA_ROWSCN inside a SP to know the recently updated/inserted rows and send them to remote (archive) database via DB links.

```
select max(ora_rowscn) max_rowscn from huge_table where ora_rowscn <= timestamp_to_scn(trunc(sysdate));
```

Then send the rows for archiving like below:

```
select * from huge_table where ora_rowscn<=max_rowscn /* from previous query */
```

Is it a good idea to do this? How is this scenario normally handled in Oracle?

Comment: I take it your DBA has investigated and discounted using [GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html)?

Comment: @Boneist Yes, we thought of taking the cheaper route first. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't want to make any major changes to your database. Otherwise, you could use an Oracle mechanism built specifically for this purpose, e.g. [Oracle Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17069/strms_change_table.htm#STRMS1519).

Querying using ORA_ROWSCN can help in your setup. But you need to be aware that it's only tracked at block level and not precise, but just an upper bound. Also see [ORA_ROWSCN Pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm).

Therefore, your solution must be capable of handling cases where rows are sent to the archive database even though they haven't changed. The other case (row has changed but is not sent) should not occur.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and yes your assumption is correct. We don't want to make any major changes and buy an Oracle license just to solve this problem. When you say there is a chance of sending the same rows, do you imply the possibility of multiple rows residing within the same block and the block gets a new ORA_ROWSCN even if only one of the record actually gets changed? If so, is there a way of finding how many records may actually reside in the same block, to calculate this probability>

Comment: Yes, that's the main case where it occurs. And I recommend post a new question to find the average number of rows in a block for the relevant table. It can be derived by querying some data dictionary views.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with solution by @Codo. Either use Oracle streams or Oracle data guard product to tackle your problem for below reasons.

1. You have a HUGE table, a full table scan is going to be very costly solution in terms of CPU and Disk resources.
2. The approach is not optimum as rowscan data is maintained at block level and you will not be able to know which of the records in block are updated. It is possible that you end up copying more than half the HUGE table in this approach, which is very resource intensive.

**Solutions**

- If you are ready to compromise performance impact during each update on your HUGE table, I suggest trigger based approach. Each time table is updated, you add an entry to identify row (even rowid, note: rowid on row is not final and can change due to multiple reasons) and store them in new table. Use this table as reference to move data to archive table. There will be impact on response time for your update actions, but this would be still lot less than approach you are considering now.
- Other option is to set up asynchronous data replication using archivelogs into your archival database. This approach is classic and involves solution outside of changes to table structure or data. This link may help you. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding [2], could you please elaborate how much probable it is to send unchanged rows?

Comment: Typical block size is 8K and changing this has impact on performance (may be positive or negative, depending on your transactions pattern ). You can figure out no. of rows in typical block. Look at this thread http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rows_per_block.htm . Make sure statistics on the table are recent otherwise avg row length may be incorrect

Comment: Since rowscan data is stored at block level, you will have to archive all rows of the block.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has option to track `ora_rowscn` at row level. 
But unfortunately this option has to be switched on during creation of table.

Always you can create new table and populate it. '`dbms_redefinition` or insert as select'
`create table xxx (blbl, ble, ble) rowdependencies;`

But one problem persist. You can not calculate row_scn for old date.

`select timestamp_to_scn(trunc(sysdate-100)) from dual;`
Query should raise excption 
`ORA-08180: no snapshot found based on specified time`.

Solution is save previous rowscn in other places